# How do I inject all implementations for a given service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How do I inject a list of all of the registered implementations for a given service interface?

```
  public class Thing
  {
      public Thing(IList<IService> services) { }
  }

  public class ServiceA : IService { }
  public class ServiceB : IService { }
  public class ServiceB : IService { }
```

Given registrations like this:

```
  public class Startup 
  {  
      public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
      {
          services
              .AddTransient<IService, ServiceA>()
              .AddTransient<IService, ServiceB>()
              .AddTransient<IService, ServiceC>();
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As of ASP.NET Core 2.0, if you inject your dependencies as `IEnumerable<IService>` instead of `IList<IService>`, you can forgo registering the list itself, leaving you with just the individual services registration.

Comment: amazing! Where can I find related documents?

Comment: @Rwing I actually discovered that by myself while fiddling with the ServiceCollection/ServiceContainer, so I don't know about any related doc.

Answer (score 10):

got it (simplified)

```
.AddTransient(p => p.GetServices<IService>())
```

but you must match the expectation of the ctor exactly so specifically for my example

```
.AddTransient<IList<IService>>(p => p.GetServices<IService>().ToList())
```